# What are these connectors called? (Often found inside of Smartphones)

Tags: connector, identification

Whats the name of these connectors?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are PCB to FPC or PCB to PCB mezzanine connectors. There are several manufacturers and pitches of these connectors. One manufacturer that comes to mind is [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/en/products/BM20/), they have a whole range of them. [Samtec](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/high-speed-board-to-board/mezzanine) also makes them, and I believe Molex makes them as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I‘ve been looking for them for ages but didnt know what to search for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is a real standard, but many companies call parts like that a mezzanine connector.  Two common uses are flex circuit-to-board and board-to-board.  Some are written into standards like VME, CompactPCI, etc.  Search for 'mezzanine card' to see many examples.